# How to replace string at the end of a large file in java?

Tags: java, file, replace

My file is very large, so I don't want to read and search the whole file. Is there a way in java I could search from the end of the file line by line, and then replace a certain part of it?

My file looks like this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
......
Line 99995
Line 99996
abc_
Line 99998
Line 99999
```

and I want to replace `abc_` to `def_`

Comment: I tried to read and search from the beginning, it takes ~50mins to do for 1 file.

Comment: Have a look at `RandomAccessFile`. Search backwards. How large is "very large" btw?

Comment: Please post the code that takes 50mins, that is far too long of a runtime for this kind of work.

Comment: What is the size of your "large" file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `FileChannel` and `ReversedLinesFileReader`.
For using reader you need to add **Appache-Commons IO** dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

First you need to find position of your line `abc_`. After that you can write line `def_` into your file using `FileChannel` and found `position`.

Code would be:

```java
import org.apache.commons.io.input.ReversedLinesFileReader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Collection;

import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.READ;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.WRITE;

String path = "path/to/your/file";
String seekingLine = "abc_";
// be careful, if replacing line is bigger 
// than seekingLine it will replace symbols after seekingLine
String replacingLine = "def_";
// finding position to replace
int seekingLinePosition = 0;
File file = new File(path);
try (ReversedLinesFileReader reader = new ReversedLinesFileReader(file)) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !line.equals(seekingLine)) {
        // + 1 because of line doesn't content line ending character
        seekingLinePosition = seekingLinePosition + line.getBytes().length + 1;
    }
}
// count seekingLine bytes for shifting
seekingLinePosition = seekingLinePosition + seekingLine.getBytes().length + 1;
// replace bytes by position
try (FileChannel fc = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(path), WRITE, READ)) {
    // shift to the start of seekingLine and write replacingLine bytes
    // +1 is because of uncounted seekingLine line ending char
    ByteBuffer replacingBytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(replacingLine.getBytes());
    fc.write(replacingBytes, fc.size() - seekingLinePosition + 1);
}
```

**Note:**

`FileChannel.write` will rewrite bytes since `position` you've passed, it means you can replace `abc_` only by line with the same length (`def_` has same length).